# Pros and Cons inline friend helper free function defined inside class for large project

Tags: c++

I am trying to list all the differences between helper friend free function defined outside class and helper friend free function defined inside the class.

I am thinking about following the rule: *declare all helper function as friend inside the body of the class* but it is not wide spread so I wonder if I have not missed some drawbacks.

Let's consider we have a namespace containing tens of classes which are ranges, for this example we put the `begin` inside the body of the class and `end` outside the body of the class (obviously the aim is not to comment this inconsistency)

```
namespace nm
{
    struct A
    {
        // ...
        auto begin();
        auto end();

        friend auto
        begin(const A& a)
        {
            return a.begin();
        }

        friend auto
        end(const A&);
    };
    
    inline auto
    end(const A& a)
    {
        return a.end();
    }

    // And tens of other class declaring `begin` and `end`.
}
```

**Pros:**

- if a user state `begin(x);` and x does not implement `begin` the program compiler will not list all the overloaded begin, since begin is only accessible if x actually implement begin helper function. (begin is not visible at namespace scope: [classes.friends],item 7 in N4659, *A friend function defined in a class is in the (lexical) scope of the class in which it is defined*). If a user declare `end(x)` and the type of x is declared in the namespace `nm` the compiler will list all the tens of `end` declaration ad potential overloads.
- begin() is not accessible through user defined conversion functions which could be unwanted.

**Cons:**

- if a user state `begin(x)` and x does not implement `begin` the user will not be informed that `begin` actually exists for other class of the namespace.
- begin() is not accessible through user defined conversion functions which could be wanted.

Have I missed some implications? What about if the helper function takes two arguments? If it is `operator==` for example?

Comment: You are wrong in stating that begin() is not visibvle at namespace scope.  Visibility is the same for begin() and end().  Remember that a friend function is not a member function.

Comment: So it may not be the right word. What I am going to look in the standard.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy C++ standard (N4659) [class.friends] item 7 *A friend function defined in a class is in the (lexical) scope of the class in which it is defined*

Comment: The scope is the same.  Friend functions have global scope, and do not belong to the structs they are friends to... Where you put the body does not really matter...   I.e.: a function can be friend to many classes, but can have only one body.

Comment: Yet, we know that in your example, you cannot refer to begin() as nm::A::begin(const A&).  It's name is nm::begin(const A&), which should give you a strong hint as to its lexical hierarchy.

Comment: a.begin() is obviously declared inside the //.. OK I add it inside the body to avoid distraction.

Comment: No need.  Whether nm::A::begin(void) exists or not doesn't change anything to the global functions .nm::begin(const A&) nm::end(const A&).

Answer (score 1):

What *"A friend function defined in a class is in the (lexical) scope of the class in which it is defined"* means is that any friend function declared in the body of A belongs to A's namespace (the lexical scope of A).

In other words:

```
namespace ns {
class A
{
    static int bar()
    {        
        return 21;
    }
public:
    inline friend int foo(A& a)
    {
        return A::bar();
    }

    friend int foo2(A& a);
};
} // namespace ns


int foo2(ns::A& a)    // this will fail, since only ns::foo2() is friend of A
{
    return foo(a);
}

namespace ns {

int foo2(ns::A& a)    // this works
{
    return foo(a);
}
} // namespace ns


int main(int, const char**, const char**)
{
    ns::A var;
    return ns::foo(var) + ns::foo2(var);
}
```

Comment: Really you are missing something. You de not answer the question. What you are explaining is that ADL (Argument Dependent Look up) also known as Koening Look up only find names declared inside the direct enclosing namespace of the argument type. So far, so good, this is basic C++ knowledge no?? What I am talking about is the fact that if the friend function is defined inside the class body and if it is not further declared outside the class, it is not visible at namespace scope... Look carefully error message here [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/tc22N5)

Comment: I use friend functions all the time, and never had this issue.  In the example above, `foo()` _is_ visible within `ns` _and_ from the global namespace.

Comment: It is because you have allways declared or defined friend function outside the class. It is not an issue it is intentionnaly stated in the standard, in order to somehow restrict ADL. My question is about if it is or not good practice. I believe so because it avoid unwanted conversions... but i still have doubts.